# Glyphicons don´t show up with Rails 4.2 and Bootstrap 3.3.3 in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I don´t see the glyphicons when I load the main page with a proper code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> Star
</button>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star</a>
```

I have fonts in `/app/assets/fonts/bootstrap`.

In the **applications.js** file:

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets 
//= require bootstrap
```

In the **application.css.scss** file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

In the **Gemfile** file:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

In the **_glyphicons.scss** file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot'));
  src: url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff2'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff2')) format('woff2'),
       url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff')) format('woff'),
       url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.ttf'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.ttf')) format('truetype'),
       url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.svg##{$icon-font-svg-id}'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.svg##{$icon-font-svg-id}')) format('svg');
}
```

And in the **_variables.scss** file:

```
$icon-font-path: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "bootstrap/", "../fonts/bootstrap/") !default;

//** File name for all font files.
$icon-font-name:          "glyphicons-halflings-regular" !default;
//** Element ID within SVG icon file.
$icon-font-svg-id:        "glyphicons_halflingsregular" !default;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: No. I don´t get any errors in my console

Comment: it already works. I have just followed the installation instructions on  [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass). With the gem it is not necessary to copy scss, js and fonts in any directory.

Comment: you also don't need to include both `bootstrap-sprockets` and `bootstrap` in `application.js` file. You need only one of those.

Comment: Is the `application.css` file deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Well... I'm not sure if you solved your problem yet.  But I had encountered the same issue before, and it wasn't based on the code, your code looks like it should work just fine.

**The problem may have been your browser security settings**.  For example if you were using **Internet Explorer** it may be in a certain security state, which **restricts the downloading of fonts, and the Glyphicons are treated as fonts.**

So go to the Security Tab of Internet Options Menu and enable font download.

---

*Unfortunately, there will always be a small amount of people that have such security settings enable and will never see the Glyphicons, so they should always be used with plain-text and not stand-alone.*